# How Parse id in flask app using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to get an element in my database using his ID but the format of my id when I get it it's <id 1> but I want only the number

I think the problem come from my `__repr__` function in my model :

```
class Table(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "tables"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
family = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
tablename = db.Column(db.String(), unique = True, nullable = False)

def __init__(self, family, tablename):
    self.family = family
    self.tablename = tablename

def __repr__(self):
    return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)

def serialize(self):
    return {
        'id': self.id,
        'family': self.family,
        'tablename': self.tablename
    }
```

and I get the id like that :

```
tablesArray = tables.Table.query.all()
for table in tablesArray:
        print(tables.Table.query.get(table))
```

Should I parse the result by myself or does it have a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reformat that `__repr__` function to deliver the integer value of ID column.

Maybe better is to create a `__str__` function alongside it, doing just that, and you call that method with `str(object)`.

Your DB table class then looks like this:

```
class Table(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "tables"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
family = db.Column(db.String(), nullable = False)
tablename = db.Column(db.String(), unique = True, nullable = False)

def __init__(self, family, tablename):
    self.family = family
    self.tablename = tablename

def __repr__(self):
    return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)

def __str__(self):
    return self.id
```

And your calling code looks like this:
(As a separate adjustment, simplified since the query is directly iterable):

```
tablesArray = tables.Table.query.all()
for table in tablesArray:
    print(str(tablesArray))
```